# What does failure to converge mean in SPSS regression?

Tags: logistic-regression, spss

Can someone clarify what the bolded text means?

"Particular attention should be paid to any contingency table with a zero (frequency) cell, since in that situation, **most standard logistic regression software packages will fail to converge and produce a point estimate for one of the odds ratios of either zero or infinity**. An intermediate strategy for dealing with this problem is to collapse categories of the independent variable in some sensible fashion to eliminate the zero cell"

This text is from Hosmer, D., Lemeshow, S., & Sturdivant, R. (2013). Applied Logistic Regression (Third Edit.)

Thanks

Comment: You should be posting this on the stats StackExchange site.

Comment: Side note, a quick google found this: http://study.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/spss_tip_20.1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if an algorithm fails to converge, it can't find one solution. That might be either because it needs to divide by zero or that - if it is iterative - jumps between several solutions. Without being an expert in logistic regression, in your situation, it should be the first case.

In my opinion, that is why the text suggests to collapse categories. That should eliminate the zero because the sum of two or more cells will be greater zero if there is one none-zero cell involved.